# How to store column values of mysql database in a list or directories using python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Lets say Active is a column in database(Data_prem) and I want to select all the rows which are having 'Active' = 1
So, this will be the code in python to store it in **a** variable

> A1_Prem = Data_Prem[Data_Prem['Active']==1]    #A1=Active{1} of Prem

**But what if there are so many columns and I want to select rows independently shall I use list or directories to store them and call them ?,
Because storing them in different variables will make code long,
Is there any other way ?,
Please help**